# AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification keeps getting called

Tags: ios, notifications, avaudiosession

I'm using AVAudioSession to get info about route changes -

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(currentRouteChanged:)
                                                 name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:nil];
```

The problem is that after closing the current session -

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    // close down our current session
    [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
```

The notification still getting called.

Currently i'm using -

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

to stop the callings but it doesn't fill right. If there is no session how come this notification is getting called?

Is there a "stronger" way to kill the audio session instead of -

```
[audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
```

that will get this notification from getting called?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If there is no session

There is *always* an audio session. It is a shared singleton, just like the application, or the notification center or user defaults.  Its existence has nothing to do with its activation. The audio session exists from the moment your app launches to the moment it is killed. As the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringanAudioSession/ConfiguringanAudioSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH2-SW1) say:

> Upon launch, your app automatically gets a singleton audio session

There is no such thing as "close down the current session".
Your idea, to unregister for notifications you no longer want, is correct. Or ignore them when they arrive.

Comment: a bit condescending but sounds good, thank you for your answer.
Also i thought that was the case and tried to just register to the notification without activating a session at all and the notification was NOT called when changing the route. 
Do you know why?

Comment: It's not a matter of condescending. You are make a false assumption on a very important matter, as shown by your talk of "closing" and "killing" the audio session. I'm trying to persuade you out of it. Even now you don't seem persuaded, but I don't know what else I can say.

Comment: The audio session is not going to start sending notifications until you've configured it. This saves the runtime from doing somework. Once you've done that, however, it persists.

Comment: Also, think about how an interruption works. The audio session is deactivated. When the interruption is over, the audio session notifies your app so you can reactivate it. It couldn't do that if deactivated audio sessions didn't send notifications.